# How to copy words from a text file to an array on C

Tags: c

How do you copy word by word into array? This code just prints the content(sentences) of a text file. I need to find the length of every word etc.. If I copy the words into an array I can edit those simply and easily(I am beginner)!

```
 #include <stdio.h> 
 #include <stdlib.h>  
 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
 FILE *myinput; 
 int count=0; 
 char k;

 myinput = fopen("board.txt", "rt"); 

 while(k!=EOF){
    k = fgetc(myinput);
    printf("%c", k);
        }
 return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Your code has a horrible, horrible mistake: If `k == EOF`, you must not attempt to read it, so the order of your checks is wrong. Also, `k` must be `int` in order to represent `EOF`. (All this is documented [in the manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html).)

Comment: The code work fine and prints the sentence from the text file without any warning!

Comment: Me? I copied pasted and ran my code!

Comment: I mean to solve your problem.

Comment: @dualed The answer is accepted! You can take a look if you want. But thank you for your time!

Comment: @user3599630 you are missing the point of my comment, but it's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should get you going.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
  int n = 1, i = 0;
  char arr[100][10];
  FILE *ptr;
  ptr = fopen("/tmp/test.txt", "r");
  while(n > 0)
    {
      n = fscanf(ptr, "%s",arr[i]);

      i++;
    }
  n = i;
  for(i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    printf("%s  length:%d\n",arr[i],(int)strlen(arr[i]));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: All users up vote this great answer!  It works fine!

Comment: Thanks user3599630..:) If this has helped you then you can accept it!

Comment: Accepted! If you think this question may help other beginners/students you can vote up!

Comment: @user3599630: Just keep in mind that this will get you going for as long as your file does not contain more than 100 words, and each word is not longer than 9 characters (i.e., it will most likely get you "crashed" under any other circumstances).

Comment: @barakmanos obviously! it will..but should I update my answer?

Comment: Maybe change 100 to 1000 and 10 to 50

Comment: Nope..looks like barakmanos is trying to suggest dynamic memory allocation!

Answer (score 0):

You can read the entire file into an array of characters, and then do whatever you want to do with it:

```
myinput = fopen("board.txt","rt");
fseek(myinput,0,SEEK_END);
int size = ftell(myinput);
fseek(myinput,0,SEEK_SET);
char* data = malloc(size);
fread(data,size,1,myinput);
fclose(myinput);
```

For example, here is how you can count the number of words (separated by white-spaces) in it:

```
#define IS_WHITE_SPACE(c) ((c)==' ' || (c)=='\n' || (c)=='\r' || (c)=='\t')

int GetNumOfWords(char* data,int size)
{
    int i;
    int numOfWords = 0;
    int wordStarted = 0;

    for (i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        if (wordStarted)
        {
            if (IS_WHITE_SPACE(data[i]))
            {
                numOfWords++;
                wordStarted = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!IS_WHITE_SPACE(data[i]))
            {
                wordStarted = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return numOfWords;
}
```

Of course, this simple task can also be achieved without reading the entire file beforehand.

However, it should make it easier on you when it comes to more sophisticated operations.

BTW, don't forget to `free(data)` when you're done...